# Trouble with nested if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

The project has to do several things with park attendance. The issues that I'm having are that when I ask the user for input and set it with 
"entering = kb.nextInt();"    or the same for the exit option it seems that the program isn't stepping through conditional logic as I think it should. It Will meet a condition and then some that it shouldn't either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've already emailed my professor and my project isn't due for a couple of days I just wanted to finish and polish it early.  [Screenshot of code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dJjI.png)

```
import java.util.Scanner;//import Scanner
import java.text.DecimalFormat;//import formatter

public class ParkAttendance
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //used for user input   
        Scanner kb =  new Scanner(System.in);
        //used to format currency
        DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00"); 
        //used to format average
        DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#.0"); 

        //----------------User Input----------------------------------
        int menuChoice = 0;//menu choice
        int subMenuChoice = 0;//menu choice     
        //-----------------Calculations-------------------------------
        int exitCounter = 0;//number of times exits were entered
        int enterCounter = 0;//number of times entries were entered 
        int highestAttendance = 0;//holds highest attendance
        int currentAttendance = 0;//holds current attendance
        int entering ;// people entering the park
        int exiting ;//people exiting the park 
        boolean black = false;//boolean for in the black or red check
        double avgEnter = 0;//average number of people entering the park
        double avgExit = 0;//average number of people exiting the park
        double income = 0;// income made for the day
        //-----------------------Constants----------------------------
        final int CAPACAITY = 250;//capacity of the park
        final double TICKET = 7.5;//ticket cost
        final int OP_COST = 2250;//operating costs for the park

        //prompt for user menu
        System.out.println("1. Display Park Attendance"
                        +"\n2. Update Attendance"
                        +"\n3. End Attendance Tracker\n");




        //The user menu
        do
        {
            menuChoice = kb.nextInt();

                //Display currentAttendance
                if(menuChoice == 1) 
                {   
                    System.out.println("Current Attendance:" + currentAttendance );
                }


                //Attendance updater    
                if(menuChoice == 2)
                {   
                    System.out.println("1. People have entered the park"
                                    +"\n2. People have left the park\n");
                    subMenuChoice = kb.nextInt();


                        if(subMenuChoice ==1)
                        {   //Prompt for input
                            System.out.println("Enter the number of people entering the park: ");
                            entering = kb.nextInt();



                            //change attendance as long as it's less than 250 and adjust currentAttendance
                            if(entering > 0)
                            {
                                currentAttendance += entering;


                                if(currentAttendance > 250)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Please wait until some people have left the park!");
                                    currentAttendance -= entering;


                                }
                                else if (currentAttendance <= 250);
                                {
                                    System.out.println(entering + " People have entered the park!");
                                    enterCounter += 1;
                                    income += (entering * TICKET);
                                }   
                            }   
                            if(entering < 0);
                            {
                                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
                                entering = 0;
                            }   


                        }   


                        if(subMenuChoice == 2)
                        {   //Prompt for input 
                            System.out.println("Enter the number of people exiting the park: ");
                            exiting = kb.nextInt();


                            //check to see if user entered a positive value
                            if(exiting < 0);
                            {
                                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
                                currentAttendance = 0;
                                exitCounter = 0;
                            }
                            if(exiting > 0)
                            {
                                System.out.println(exiting + " people have left the park!");    
                                currentAttendance -= exiting;
                                exitCounter += 1;
                            }   


                        }   



                    }//end of attendance updater 







                //re-prompt for menu
                System.out.println("1. Display Park Attendance"
                        +"\n2. Update Attendance"
                        +"\n3. End Attendance Tracker\n");


        }while(menuChoice != 3);//end of do while


        //calculate average entries and exits
        if(enterCounter >0 && exitCounter >0)
        {   
            avgEnter = currentAttendance/enterCounter;
            avgExit = currentAttendance/exitCounter;
        }
        //calculate if operating costs were met
        if(income > OP_COST)
        {
            black = true;
        }       

        //display calculations and end program
        System.out.print("The highest attendance was: " + highestAttendance
                        +"\n Average number of people entering:" + decimal.format(avgEnter)
                        +"\n Average number of people exiting: " + decimal.format(avgExit)
                        +"\n Income earned: " + currency.format(income) 
                        +"\n In the black: " + black);

    }//end of main
}//end of Project2
```

Comment: Have you tried running your program in your debugging and stepping through your code as it executes? This is the usual way to solve this sort of problem.

Comment: I'm literally just using notepad++ and cmd prompt. I've tried to follow it myself but I can't figure out where my issue is.

Comment: i can answer this, but you better try out by your self to make you more skilled on problem solving (y)

Comment: Damn, I've been working on it for a couple hours at this point. Lol.

Comment: I suggest you stop using just notepad++ and learn how to use an IDE and a debugger. Going through your code line-by-line with a debugger to follow the execution and see the values of each variable on each line will solve your problems.

Comment: Cant use an IDE for this class, against the rules.

Comment: Ohh. OK. I'm confused now that using a debugger is prohibited but getting StackOverflow to debug this for you is allowed.

Comment: If you don't want to help you don't have to. Snarky comments really don't benefit anyone in this situation. I've only put this on here after I've tried running this several different ways. If I could use an IDE and knew how I would've done it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, you have a semicolon at "if(entering < 0);" so that will always display. Also you have a semicolon at "if(exiting < 0);" so that will always display too. You should also check to make sure that number of people leaving does not exceed the number of people currently in the park. Also you are never doing anything with highestAttendance. Your avgEnter and avgExit are always going to be 0 because of integer division. It is truncating the values (int)/(int). You can easily fix this by typecasting one or both of the ints to doubles, like             "avgEnter = currentAttendance/ (double) enterCounter;" Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Looking at this for a while, those semicolons started to blended in for me. That fixed my problems and now I can work on polishing it up!

Comment: Yeah no problem!